# How to get elements from an object in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, object, autocompletebox

I am using the AutoCompleteBox in WPF, I populate the suggestions with a List that consists of four fields. When the user selects an item and I reach my eventHandler, i can see that

```
MyAutoCompleteBox.SelectedItem
```

is an object that has my four values, if i hover this text in the debugger i can see the four values listed, however i don't know how to access these values in the code.

I tried

```
List<Codes> selected = MyAutoCompleteBox.SelectedItem as List<Codes>;
```

where Codes is my List. selected returns as null and empty every time. Is there a way to get to these values? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to check what type your MyAutoCompleteBox.SelectedItem.GetType() returns ?

Comment: the Name = "Codes" and the FullName="MyNamespace.Codes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
Codes selected = MyAutoCompleteBox.SelectedItem as Codes;
```

or

```
Codes[] selected = MyAutoCompleteBox.SelectedItem as Codes[];
```

Comment: ahh that was it, just needed to remove the List part. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the listing of items used as the backing collection for the `AutoCompleteBox` try...[AutoCompleteBox.ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox.itemssource%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

Comment: yes the list of Codes is what i have set as my itemsource, just need to retrieve when one is selected

Answer (score 1):

It means that you cannot convert whatever MyAutoCompleteBox.SelectedItem is to a List.

Comment: its not crucial that i convert it to a list, just need to access the values so i can search on them